# I need some help with this 15x15 nonogram

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, nonogram

[image: Hard nonogram]

I have been working on this nonogram for some time and can't seen to figure out what to do next...

This is the link: https://nonograms-katana.com/play/#game

Comment: how come there are 2 pictures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the seventh column:

> With the X at the top of the column, you can completely fill out the rest of the column.

Answer (score 2):

Row, 5 column 15 must be an X, which then yields additional deductions for column 15.

Answer (score 1):

1. In the fifth row,

   > the rightmost $3$ can't start from the right-hand edge, because then it would become $4$ with the black cell you've already filled. So the rightmost cell in this row is empty (cross).

   Then in the rightmost column,

   > there's not enough space for the $6$ *above* the fifth row, so all those cells are empty. Now there's ten unknown cells to contain that $6$, so the middle two of them at least must be black. That enables you to cross off the rightmost $1$ in two rows.
2. In the fourth row,

   > if the lone black cell in the middle is the $1$, then there must be $3$ to the left of it with an empty cell in between. Then, reading down from the columns, the three cells below that $3$ must be empty, but then the fifth row won't have enough space for its $3,1,3$. Contradiction, so the fourth row can be completely filled in up to the middle (two empty cells then two black cells).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple of different places you can go from there, I'll leave the rest for you to solve:

> [image]

Red squares are black, and grey squares are crosses, using colours to highlight.

Quick explanation:

> The top most red must be filled in, regardless whether the other black to the right is part of the 1 or the 3. This greys out the square below, and means the red 3 can be placed as it cannot fit to the right. Furthermore, the bottom grey on the right cannot be filled, as that would make a 4, and from that some of the 6 can be placed.

Good luck! If you need a bit more I can add some